# css font properties Vs text properties

Tags: css

After referring these two links (font properties and text properties), I have a doubt.

What is font? and what is text?

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_reference.asp#font

http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_reference.asp#text

For example both color, font-size describes typography but why they placed in two different categories?

I'm missing some thing basically. What is it? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Font is purely for control of Font related attributes whereas Text controls things that go beyond just the Font (such as alignment, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Font is somehow like properties of the text, like :

```
Font-size:15px;
Font-Family: Sans Serif;
Font-Color: Red;
```

Text are the one that you will print on the browser,

Font is the CSS Property.

For more info refer this link : [CSS Text & Font Properties](https://www.brotsky.tv/2014/10/04/building-a-website-part-7-css-text-font-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

Font is how the letters look like. Text is where to place them...

Comment: Except for text-decoration, which actually affects what the letters look like. And also text-transform.  There's also color, which is neither text nor font, but affects how it looks.

Comment: Decoration isn't really defined in the font itself, transform just chooses which characters to show within the current font. You have to look at a Font just as the curves/pixels required for each character. Everything else is at a different, unrelated level. Although I agree the distinction can be blurry for some properties.

Comment: @Wim Also refer: font-variant: normal, small-caps; and text-transform: uppercase, capitalize, lowercase. These are not obeying your definition.

Comment: Uppercase/lowercase do not change the font, they change the character code. Small-caps is a bit different, since most fonts indeed have a special version (or at least a scale factor of their uppercase set) for rendering the small caps...